# Selenium upload videos in a drop to upload box

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver

Hello guys I need to upload a video in a website that gives a drop to upload box, I tried to sendkeys to that box but it didn't work 'raise object interactable error', any ideas thanks in advance.
[the upload area in the page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1CXuF.png)

[the page html](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2XDnz.png)

i have tried this but it doesnt work.

```
upload_btn = driver.find_element_by_id('upload-clickable')
upload_btn.send_keys('videos/{}'.format(video))
```

Comment: Try adding a wait before selecting the element. If that doesn't work, perhaps try using the full xpath

Comment: yeah i have a time sleep of 5 sec after the page load, and the find by xpath didnt work either.